# "Petali di rose" o "petali di rosa"?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Il testo della bella canzone "Estate" è sempre scritto con la frase "Cadranno mille petali di rose". Quella frase dovrebbe invece essere "Cadranno mille petali di rosa"?

Comment: Una rosa non ha mille petali, ne servono varie... :) Scusa, è poco più di una battuta, ma a orecchio “petali di rosa” mi suona un po' insolito.

Comment: E "petali di rose"? Come suona?

Comment: Al mio orecchio suona normale, ma sto parlando solo per me. Magari c'entrano varietà regionali. Da una rapidissima ricerca con Google Ngrams (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=petali+di+rose%2Cpetali+di+rosa&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=33&smoothing=3), per quel che vale, sembrerebbe effettivamente che “...di rosa” sia prevalente, ma a partire da anni recenti.

Comment: Quando ci si riferisce al testo di una canzone, bisogna tener presente che la sua funzione è produrre arte, non un compendio di grammatica o linguistica. "_Cadranno mille petali di rose_" si comprende alla perfezione e rima con "_La neve coprirà tutte le cose_" quindi è come deve essere per raggiungere il suo scopo. ;)

Comment: D'altra parte, non credo che qualcuno perda il sonno quando sente "_She don't lie / She don't lie / She don't lie / Cocaine_", no?

Comment: @DaG Sarà, ma a me sembra insolito “petali di rose”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ambedue queste espressioni, ["petali di rose"](http://www.gdli.it/Ricerca/Sequenza?q=petali+di+rose) e ["petali di rosa"](http://www.gdli.it/Ricerca/Sequenza?q=petali+di+rosa) sono in uso, come si evince dalla ricerca in sequenza delle stringhe correspondenti sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*.

Troviamo un esempio di uso di "petali di rosa" nelle *Sorelle Materassi* di Aldo Palazzeschi:

> A queste gioie terrene si aggiungevano quelle celesti, le benedizioni che la buona e infelice sorella dal cielo lasciava cadere come petali di rosa sopra le loro teste.

Curiosamente, però, nella lettura di questo romanzo che si fa nel [programma "Ad alta voce"](https://www.raiplayradio.it/audio/2015/05/Sorelle-Materassi---Lettura-IX-5477600c-ee61-49fe-abac-942439f19453.html) di Rai Radio 3, [Paolo Poli](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paolo_Poli) pronuncia chiaramente "petali di rose" (lo potete sentire al minuto 9:30), magari perché abitava a Roma e, come @DaG, si era abituato a questa espressione.

Qualcosa di più recente si trova su un [articolo della *Stampa* del 1990](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI23/00563.jpg) citato nel dizionario sopra menzionato:

> Le giacchette lievi come petali di rosa stanno in un pugno, sono in microfibra, seta, lana, daino, cotone trattato.

Ed ecco un [esempio di "petali di rose"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI09/00000618.jpg) tratto dal libro *Contrada dei gatti* di Achille Giovanni Cagna:

> Coppie di angioletti con cestelli spandono sulla via a manciate petali di rose, di dalie e di ortensie spampanate.

Nel primo link al *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, si trovano altre esempi in poesie di Carlo Vallini, di Sergio Corazzini e di Giovanni Pascoli,
e anche nella definizione di ["aceto rosato"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00106.jpg), che riporto qui sotto:

> *Aceto rosato*:
> nel quale sono stati posti a macerare petali di rose.

Comment: Il senso nell'ultima frase è leggermente diverso: l'idea è che sono stati spampanati molti fiori: rose, dalie e ortensie; i petali sono poi sparsi.

Comment: Va bene, @egreg: ho riportato un altro esempio.

Comment: Ottimo. Rafforza la mia convinzione che “petali di rosa” vada per il senso figurato, mentre “petali di rose” per il senso letterale.

Comment: Ancora un'altra aggiunta, @egreg.

Comment: @egreg: Nel caso di fiori e petali, non capisco la distinzione tra uso letterale e figurativo.

Comment: @RalphDratman In “le giacchette lievi come petali di rosa” l'uso è figurato.

Comment: @Charo, grazie per la tua risposta. Per favore, scusa la mia ignoranza. Sono un nuovo studente della lingua italiana. Mi sembra che la differenza tra "rosa" e "rose" sia una questione di singolare contro plurale. Ho ragione?

Comment: Sì, @RalphDratman: "rosa" è singolare, invece "rose" è plurale.